# How can I "compress" a known homogenous coordinate affine transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, numerical-methods, soft-question, numerical-linear-algebra

Having worked with geometry I am aware of homogenous coordinates and affine transformations. With linear algebra we can express it as

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}R&T\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

Where $$x_0 \to x_1 - \text{our transformation}\\T - \text{translation vector}\\R - \text{rotation matrix}$$

I would like to compress it. So that instead of (in 3D) having to store the 3x3 + 3x1  = 12 floating point numbers, I can get away with say... $\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3,S,t_1,t_2,t_3$ where $R = SR_3R_2R_1, T = [t_1,t_2,t_3]^t$

$$R_1 = \begin{bmatrix}\cos(\phi_1)&\sin(\phi_1)&0\\-\sin(\phi_1)&\cos(\phi_1)&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$R_2 = \begin{bmatrix}\cos(\phi_2)&0&\sin(\phi_2)\\0&1&0\\-\sin(\phi_2)&0&\cos(\phi_2)\end{bmatrix}$$

$$R_3 = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\cos(\phi_3)&\sin(\phi_3)\\0&-\sin(\phi_3)&\cos(\phi_3)\end{bmatrix}$$

How can this be done?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles seems relevant. Also [tag:soft-question] is probably not appropriate

Comment: Euler angles is a common representation, but not necessarily a good representation.  The slightly over-complete representations cover the entire space with fewer singularity-type issues.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions